# Old anime where a kid fuses/merges with a white tiger spirit or god

Tags: story-identification, anime, manga

I’m looking for a manga. I can’t remember if it’s by Viz media or Tokyopop but my school used to have it in its library. There was a kid that fused/merged with a white tiger spirit or god or something, his friends proceed to get similar powers, just different animals

Comment: Just to confirm, you're looking for a book/graphic novel, not a TV series or movie series?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it could be the Line Webtoon [Flow](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/flow/list?title_no=101), which was published online 2014-2016 and [republished in print 2018](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WNGFBWD).

> A fantasy comic about a boy's destiny that starts to change as he receives a gift from his guardian god. [[Webtoon Fandom](https://webtoon.fandom.com/wiki/Flow#Synopsis)]

In this world each person has a "Guardian God" or "Anima" and the main character's turns out to be the White Tiger.

> Yun Lee-Rang is a young man with a cat anima. After being beat up and put into the hospital his cat anima is revealed to be one of the strongest animas in disguise; the White Tiger. The White Tiger anima allows him to cast a wish and he uses it to turn back time. He soon repeats the cycle of his day but several consequences were found with turning back time. [ibid]